# How to find filtered ports using nmap

Tags: networking, nmap

How do i list all the filtered ports using nmap?
i have used the command sudo nmap -sS -v
how can we print the list of the ports should i use -sU ,-sX or any other parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@mg0008 ~]# nmap server1 -p 8081-8088 | grep filtered
8081/tcp filtered blackice-icecap
8083/tcp filtered unknown
8085/tcp filtered unknown
8086/tcp filtered unknown
8087/tcp filtered unknown
8088/tcp filtered unknown
```

Only Port number

```
[root@us-wal-mg0008 ~]# nmap svp1ws3 -p 8081-8088 | grep filtered | grep -e ^[0-9] | awk '{print $1}'
8081/tcp
8083/tcp
8085/tcp
8086/tcp
8087/tcp
8088/tcp
```